# HTTP Client requests done right

Tags: java, http, client

As advised by many, I am using a client pool - specifically the Apache  [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html).

For simplicity I wrap it in my own simple singleton class. Sorry about the rather OTT `Stop` mechanism:

```
public final class HttpClientPool {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClientPool.class);

  // Single-element enum to implement Singleton.
  private static enum Singleton {
    // Just one of me so constructor will be called once.
    Client;
    // The thread-safe client.
    private final CloseableHttpClient threadSafeClient;
    // The pool monitor.
    private final IdleConnectionMonitorThread monitor;

    // The constructor creates it - thus late
    private Singleton() {
      PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
      // Increase max total connection to 200
      cm.setMaxTotal(200);
      // Increase default max connection per route to 20
      cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
      // Build the client.
      threadSafeClient = HttpClients.custom()
              .setConnectionManager(cm)
              .build();
      // Start up an eviction thread.
      monitor = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(cm);
      // Don't stop quitting.
      monitor.setDaemon(true);
      monitor.start();
    }

    public CloseableHttpClient get() {
      return threadSafeClient;
    }

  }

  public static CloseableHttpClient getClient() {
    // The thread safe client is held by the singleton.
    return Singleton.Client.get();
  }

  // Watches for stale connections and evicts them.
  private static class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {
    // The manager to watch.
    private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
    // Use a BlockingQueue to stop everything.
    private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stopSignal = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);

    // Pushed up the queue.
    private static class Stop {
      // The return queue.
      private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stop = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);

      // Called by the process that is being told to stop.
      public void stopped() {
        // Push me back up the queue to indicate we are now stopped.
        stop.add(this);
      }

      // Called by the process requesting the stop.
      public void waitForStopped() throws InterruptedException {
        // Wait until the callee acknowledges that it has stopped.
        stop.take();
      }

    }

    IdleConnectionMonitorThread(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm) {
      super();
      this.cm = cm;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // Holds the stop request that stopped the process.
        Stop stopRequest;
        // Every 5 seconds.
        while ((stopRequest = stopSignal.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) == null) {
          // Close expired connections
          cm.closeExpiredConnections();
          // Optionally, close connections that have been idle too long.
          cm.closeIdleConnections(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          // Look at pool stats.
          log.trace("Stats: {}", cm.getTotalStats());
        }
        // Acknowledge the stop request.
        stopRequest.stopped();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // terminate
      }
    }

    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
      log.trace("Shutting down client pool");
      // Signal the stop to the thread.
      Stop stop = new Stop();
      stopSignal.add(stop);
      // Wait for the stop to complete.
      stop.waitForStopped();
      // Close the pool - Added
      threadSafeClient.close();
      // Close the connection manager.
      cm.close();
      log.trace("Client pool shut down");
    }

  }

  public static void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
    // Shutdown the monitor.
    Singleton.Client.monitor.shutdown();
  }

}
```

I use it exclusively with JSON requests:

```
  // General query of the website. Takes an object of type Q and returns one of class R.
  public static <Q extends JSONObject, R> R query(String urlBase, String op, Q q, Class<R> r) throws IOException {
    // The request.
    final HttpRequestBase request;
    //postRequest.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    if (q != null) {
      // Prepare the post.
      HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlBase + op);
      // Get it all into a JSON string.
      StringEntity input = new StringEntity(asJSONString(q));
      input.setContentType("application/json");
      postRequest.setEntity(input);
      // Use that one.
      request = postRequest;
    } else {
      // Just get.
      request = new HttpGet(urlBase + op);
    }
    log.debug("> " + urlBase + op + (q == null ? "" : " " + q));
    // Post it and wait.
    return readResponse(request, HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(request), r);
  }
  public static <R> R readResponse(HttpRequestBase request, CloseableHttpResponse response, Class<R> r) throws IOException {
    // What was read.
    R red = null;
    try {
      // What happened?
      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Roll out the results
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
          InputStream content = entity.getContent();
          try {
            // Roll it directly from the response stream.
            JsonParser rsp = getFactory().createJsonParser(content);
            // Bring back the response.
            red = rsp.readValueAs(r);
          } finally {
            // Always close the content.
            content.close();
          }
        }
      } else {
        // The finally below will clean up.
        throw new IOException("HTTP Response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
      }
    } finally {
      // Always close the response.
      response.close();
    }

    if (red == null) {
      log.debug("< {null}");
    } else {
      log.debug("< {}", red.getClass().isArray() ? Arrays.toString((Object[]) red) : red.toString());
    }
    return red;
  }
```

This seems to work fine under normal load - however, a recent high-load period caused everything to fall apart. We even interfered with other hosted apps. Not sure what caused the interference but I want to be sure this side of it is done right.

The exceptions I saw were:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect -- Thousands of these per hour!!!
```

So - my questions:

1. Am I using the pool correctly?
2. Am I closing/not closing at the right time?
3. Should I reset the request (`request.reset()`)?
4. Have I missed something?

---

**Added**

Spot the *deliberate mistake* - not closing the `threadSafeClient` at `shutdown` time. Not relevant to the issue but important. Fixed!

Also - failing to close the stream and checking the entity against null. Fixed!

Comment: Could you specify the version of the library you're using ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre - httpcomponents version 4.3.3 - thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Marc-Andre - I forgot! The problem occurred while I was using 4.2.5 and a slightly less streamlined close mechanism. I am primarily interested in confirmation that this way is **right**.

Comment: As I was suspecting the Http Apache changes a lot with each version, so that's why I've ask for the version, I'm glad you resolve your problem. I'll see if I can come up with an answer but everything looks fine so far.

Comment: @Marc-Andre - May also be significant that I am running under Java 5.

Comment: You know what's funny? We're dealing with http connections not closing themselves and when I looked at the code, well all the advice I gave we're applicable to our code. Code Review is really helpful!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - slightly not related, but may I ask how much load you are able handle with this code? You wrote things started to fall off when the load was increased. Thanks!

Comment: @jagamot - The instability showed itself under pressure. The various changes I made removed the instability. Not sure of the specific causes but suspect it was failing to close the stream or the upgrade from 4.2.2 to 4.3.3.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the latest you have? And what load is it able to handle currently under what memory configurations?..only if you can share! I am in a similar boat and I see issues under load, like running OOM etc.

Comment: @jagamot - The code as posted matches the live setup in all reasonable respects. I have no metrics for it's stability under load - that is likely to be subjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the library or multithreading, so maybe some advises will not be applicable.

**TL;DR**
I didn't find anything in your code really wrong. In fact, the more I look at it, the more I can just find only nitpicking things, and I'm really forcing myself. I would find myself quite happy to maintain this code. Everything is clean, the exception managing is excellent and it's quite easy to read.

`readResponse` Looks clean to me. What is important when working with the request is to always "consume" the entity and/or close the request. At first, I thought that you had a problem when the request didn't return a `200`. When the return code is not `200` you're not consuming the `Entity` which can normally block the connection, but it seems that you don't need to consume the `Entity` if you `close()` the request. In my code, I'm still using `EntityUtils.consume()`, but it's probably overkill.

`query` seems a bit weird to me. I always see either `get` or `post` not both. I find weird that `query` can do both, since normally it's very two different things. Despite that fact, it still really well handled.

This line is a bit hard to fully grasp at first read IMO :

> ```
> return readResponse(request, HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(request), r);
> ```

I find it hard to see that this it's actually where you're making the request. It could be in it's own line, to better extract it's important role. I find it easier to debug too.

> ```
> final HttpRequestBase request;
> //postRequest.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
> ```

I guess the comment is a dead one. It could be remove since it serve no purpose. In general, I find there is a bit too much comments for my own taste, but this is basically because your code is very clean and comments are just expressing what I understand by just reading your code. (I'm really impress by the quality)

> ```
> // Post it and wait.
> ```

This one is not quite true, because you could be executing a `Get` request and not a `Post`. I'm starting to think that those methods were at first working with `Post` request and evolve into both type of request. (base on the dead comment and this one)

> ```
>  if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
> ```

Instead of `200` I would personaly use `HttpStatus.OK`.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your helpful comments. You are right in all cases - I will adjust my code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

One small correction here:

```
  // Close the pool - Added
  threadSafeClient.close();
```

Change this to:

```
// Close the pool - Added
Singleton.Client.threadSafeClient.close();
```

Explanation:

There is no `threadSafeClient` field in `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` class, thus the code fails to compile. Since this field is present in Singleton, the correct way of closing this is:

```
Singleton.Client.threadSafeClient.close();
```

This fixes the compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

You create only one Connection.
Try this:

```
private static enum Singleton {
    // Just one of me so constructor will be called once.
    Client;
    // The pool
    private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;

    // The constructor creates it - thus late
    private Singleton() {
      cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
      // Increase max total connection to 200
      cm.setMaxTotal(200);
      // Increase default max connection per route to 20
      cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    }

    public CloseableHttpClient get() {
      CloseableHttpClient threadSafeClient = HttpClients.custom()
              .setConnectionManager(cm)
              .build();
              return threadSafeClient;
    }

}
```

`